# Comprobar si password hasheada es igual al password sin hashear PHP-MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, hash

Tengo un `formulario de registro en HTML` con inputs de : `Correo, password, repetirPassword`

```
<div id="register-box">
        <form action="../php/register.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
            <p id="welcome">Bienvenido a XXXXXXX !</p>
            <p>Correo</p>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            <p>Password</p>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
            <p>Repetir password</p>
            <input type="password" name="repeatPassword" id="repeatPassword" required>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="ENTRAR">
        </form>
    </div>
```

Al enviar el formulario se ejecuta `register.php` donde compruebo si las contraseñas coinciden. Si es así, se inserta la información de los inputs a la base de datos con la `contraseña hasheada`.

```
// Inserting form data to database.
    function insertData($password, $repeatPassword) {
        if ($password==$repeatPassword) {
            $passwordHash = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            $insert = "INSERT INTO register_log(email,password) VALUES ('{$_POST['email']}','{$passwordHash}')";
                if ($GLOBALS['mysql']->query($insert)==TRUE) {
                    echo PHP_EOL . "Registro insertado correctamente" . PHP_EOL;
                }
                else {
                    echo PHP_EOL . "Error al insertar : " . $GLOBALS['mysql']->error . PHP_EOL;
                }
        }
    }
insertData($_POST['password'], $_POST['repeatPassword']);
```

Output de registro --> `16 | alexc.igg7@gmail.com | $2y$10$9xbERtSiPT3iCBsz51G89Oc/QfVwQ/lvXaTNnZfqQ.tl4anJ.4GTa`

Ahora me dispongo a realizar el `login`, donde tengo que comprobar si el correo y la contraseña entrada coinciden con la almacenada en la base de datos. Alguna sugerencia?

**NOTA**
Obviamente, si hasheao la contraseña del login, no es igual a la haseada en la base de datos (para evitar confusiones)

Comment: Si se necesita más parte del código o cualquier aclaración estoy atento a los comentarios !

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo PHP de forma autodidacta desde hace una semana, aún hay funciones que desconozco, ahora busco información sobre `password_verify`, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```php
if(password_verify($clave_login, $clave_db)){
   //usuario correcto
}
```

$clave_login: la calve ingresada en el login sin encriptar
$clave_db: la clave encriptada que guardaste en la base de datos

Enlaces relacionados:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108720/password-hash-returns-different-value-every-time

Comment: Correcto, ya había solucionado el problema, de todas formas tu respuesta lo hubiera hecho en caso de que no lo hubiese solucionado. Gracias ;D !